# How do I discover list of words from corpus which distinguish from another corpus? Python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I have two lists of unstructured text input, and I want to find the words that distinguish `listA` from `listB`. 
For example, if `listA` were the text of "Harry Potter" and `listB` were the text of "Ender's Game", the distinguishes elements for `listA` would be `[wand, magic, wizard, . . .]` and the distinguishing elements for `listB` would be `[ender, buggers, battle, . . .]`

I've tried a bit with the python-nltk module, and am able to easily find the most common words in each list, but that is not exactly what I'm after.

Comment: How does listA know about wands, magic and wizards?

Comment: I guess you would want to compare the frequency counts in each book to the frequency counts in some standard corpus. If the words are low frequency in the corpus but relatively high frequency in the books, they are distinguishing.

Comment: `topic-model` , try https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've tried a bit with the python-nltk, and am able to easily find the most common words in each list, but not exactly what I'm after

I'm guessing what you mean by this is it's coming up with words like "and", "the", "of", etc. as the words with the highest frequency. These words aren't very helpful, they are basically just the glue that holds words together to form a sentence, you could remove them but you would need a list of "useless" words called a stoplist, nltk has such a list `from nltk.corpus import stop words`.

You might want to take a look at [TF.IDF](http://www.tfidf.com) scoring. This will give a higher weight to the words that are common in one document but uncommon in general. Usually you would use a large corpora to calculate which words are common in general.

Comment: Nice, that TF.IDF scoring is giving me really good results, when fed a big corpus. Thanks for the help, jksnw

Answer (score 0):

You can use synsets to get it done. To get synsets NLTK include a very powerful library called wordnet.

Wordnet is a big 'database' (in lack of a better word) of human language, not only english, it supports many other languages.

[Synset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synonym_ring) is a like a similar idea you get when you hear a term. Almost like a synonym, but not that strict. Please, go to the link, its a better definition.

[Synset Closures](http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html#synset-closures) is what can help you the most. For example, 'bee' is a animial, a insect, a living thing; Harry Potter is fictional, human, wizard.

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
dog = wn.synset('dog.n.01')
hyper = lambda s: s.hypernyms()
list(dog.closure(hyper))
```

[Heres](https://play.google.com/store/books/details/Jacob_Perkins_Python_3_Text_Processing_with_NLTK_3?id=rAFcBAAAQBAJ) a book that teach you the surface of nltk, is not very good but is a good place to start along with [NTLK HOWTOs](http://www.nltk.org/howto/)

If you want something deeper I cant help you, I dont know most of the definitions and functions NTLK provide us, but synsets are a great place to start.